# vs c++ mysql udf crash when run

Tags: c++, mysql, c, dll

I test simple mysql udf and below is my code in VS2019 c++

```
#include "mysql.h"

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#define DLLEXP __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define DLLEXP
#endif

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    #define LIBVERSION "lib_mysqludf_udf version 0.0.3"

    DLLEXP bool test_init(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* message);
    DLLEXP long long test(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* is_null, char* error);
    DLLEXP void test_deinit(UDF_INIT* initid);
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
bool test_init(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* message) { return 0; }

long long test(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* is_null, char* error)
{
    return args->arg_count;
}

void test_deinit(UDF_INIT* initid) {}
```

in mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION test returns string soname 'myUdf.dll';
```

create sucessfully and crashed when run

```
select test('aa')   Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  2.328 sec
```

I don't have any idea what is going on. And the different result in string result. The string return code as follow

```
#include <string.h>
#include "mysql.h"

#include <stdbool.h>

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#define DLLEXP __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define DLLEXP
#endif

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    DLLEXP bool test_init(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* message);
    DLLEXP char* test(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* result, unsigned long* length, char* is_null, char* error);
    DLLEXP void test_deinit(UDF_INIT* initid);
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
bool test_init(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* message)
{
    bool status;
if (args->arg_count != 0) {
    strcpy_s(
        message, sizeof(message)
        , "No arguments allowed"
    );
    status = 1;
}
else {
    status = 0;
}
return status;
}

char* test(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* result, unsigned long* length, char* is_null, char* error)
{
    strcpy(result, "hello");
    *length = 5;
    return result;
}

void test_deinit(UDF_INIT* initid) {}
```

And the result is
[image]

Mysql 8.0 x64 and my dll is release with x64 in Win 10.

Comment: And where do you check the `result` pointer and the length of the buffer before the function is called?

Comment: sry, edited and at init function

Comment: my fault I forgot to change returns integer, now i can run INT return but string return still has the issue.

Comment: found something CONVERT(test() USING utf8) can show correctly,

Comment: Is there any way to achieve without using CONVERT?